# Alienware R3 15 or Dell XPS 15

Tags: laptop, gaming

I'm planning to buy a new laptop and planning to have is for the next 5-7 years laptop. I wanted the laptop for graphic design, programming, video editing and gaming(please don't recommend desktop setup because I'll be traveling a lot thanks).

**Alienware:**
I don't mind the heaviness since I know it has a great built quality but I the color accuracy is not that accurate like XPS.

**Chosen specs:**
-   7th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ (Quad-Core, 6MB Cache, up to 3.8GHz w/ Turbo Boost)
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1060 with 6GB GDDR5
-15.6 inch FHD (1920 x 1080) 60Hz IPS Anti-Glare 300-nits NVIDIA G-SYNC Enabled
-16GB DDR4 at 2400MHz
-   128GB M.2 SATA 6Gb/s SSD (Boot) + 1TB 7200RPM SATA 6Gb/s (Storage)
-   Killer 1535 802.11ac 2x2 WiFi and Bluetooth 4.1
- **$1,674.99**

**Dell XPS:**
I love the screen and it's almost edgeless but I'm afraid since it's too thin(probably smaller fan). Maybe it could get overheat easily for gaming and probably can be broken like 1-3 years for continuous use.

**Chosen specs:**

-7th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ Quad Core Processor (6M cache, up to 3.8 GHz)
-16GB DDR4-2400MHz
-512GB PCIe Solid State Drive
-NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 with 4GB GDDR5
-15.6" FHD (1920 x 1080) InfinityEdge
-Killer 1535 802.11ac 2x2 WiFi and Bluetooth 4.1
-97WHr battery
-$1,749.99

So I need your help guys which one is really worth it and will last for years(please include explanation too, why you chose XPS or alienware). Thanks !!!!

Comment: Thank you for asking this! I had the exact same question, but I was going to add the New Razer  Blade as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you are better off going with the Alienware R3 Laptop.

Here is a list of reasons as to why I would recommend it over the Dell XPS:

- GTX 1060 will be much more useful than the GTX 1050 in both Gaming and Content Creation (Due to the more CUDA Cores and VRAM)
- An SSD/HDD combo will net you both fast loading times as well as much more storage space
- Better value, considering you are getting a G-Sync Panel and a higher end GPU for a lower cost than the XPS

Some Notes:

If you are concerned about color accuracy and believe that you will benefit from a better display, I would suggest saving up some money for a more professional monitor to use when you plan on doing content creation.

I cannot guarantee that either of the laptops mentioned will last for over 5 years.

Comment: You might also want to look at getting a display color calibrator (like a Sypder5 or Colormunki) if you're concerned about color accuracy

Comment: MrPublic, I am very satisfied with your answer and you helped me to decide. Thank you too very much @NoahL, Yes I will. It's my first to buy a highend laptop...that's why I asked. :D